# How to perform a .substring() on a string from .match() in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Not working code:

```
var m;
val = "some text with a [tag: in it like that";
m = val.match(/\[\w+:/);
var params = m.substring(1).split(':');
```

Throws the following error in Firebug:

`val.substring is not a function`

When I do `console.log(typeof(val));` I get object, when I'm expecting a string... at least, I think it should be a string.

**How can I perform a .substring() on a "string" from .match() in Javascript?**

Comment: Your `m` array will always contain a string like `[...:`. Therefore, why would you like to split on the `:`? You can be sure that the second element of `params` will be `""`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`match()` returns an array of strings, containing the complete text of the match followed by the values of any capturing groups.

You can call `m[0].substring`.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks... I suppose it should be obvious right, what if .match() matches more than once, right? lol! Thx.

Comment: @Chad: `match` can only return the first match.  The array stores group captures.

Answer (score 2):

variable `m` is an array not a string: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/4GLKs/